# Why does the cover of the 5th TombQuest book not have an amulet?

Tags: michael-northrop, tombquest

The first 4 books in *TombQuest* all have an amulet featured on the cover:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

<sub>(Images from [Scholastic](http://tombquest.scholastic.com/books).)</sub>

And then... the fifth book:

[image]

It features this really cool scary guy, who I'm assuming is Anubis, and makes a cool profile pic for the [Twitter](https://twitter.com/tombquestwiki). But... why was the decision made to change the style?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not familiar with the series, but do the plots of the first four books involve amulets, but the fifth doesn't?

Comment: Confession time - I've only read the first one, but it was strongly implied that amulets were important. They're featured in the game as well.

Comment: Aha. Okay, then. So...you run a Wikia and a Twitter account for a series that you've only read 20% of? That's some dedication :)

Comment: I was in charge of those before any of the books came out :P I was one of the 50 beta testers for the game :)

Comment: I see. I checked the Wikia pages of each of the books. The first three do mention amulets as either trivia or plot points; the last two only contain (what I assume is) the official synopsis on the back of the books.